# Is is correct to use a trained kohonen map for classification?

Tags: classification, clustering

I know that kohonen map is algorithm for clustering data, so I want to know if it is correct to use a trained Kohonen map as a classifier or if it is better to say that the kohonen map finds the data structure and then I use a minimum distance classifier to perform the classification, that is to assign  a label to a new sample ( one that was not used on training) as the the label if the neuron which is closest to the new sample.